# I have some problem python packages in Google Compute engine

Tags: python, linux, google-compute-engine, ccxt

I want to my code running for 24 hours.

So i made Google Cloude Compute Engine instance

and tried install python and other packages

but ccxt package has a error to install

this is error sentence

```
~$ pip3 install ccxt
Collecting ccxt
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/78/ec/1b33bd878c88898079e8582d01ad7f6e9d7b99377015e768537269
9cf7e5/ccxt-1.73.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: aiohttp>=3.8; python_version >= "3.5.2" in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (fro
m ccxt) (3.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.18.4 in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from ccxt) (2.27.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=2.6.1 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from ccxt) (2.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: yarl==1.7.2; python_version >= "3.5.2" in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from
 ccxt) (1.7.2)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2018.1.18 in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from ccxt) (2021.10.8)
Collecting aiodns>=1.1.1; python_version >= "3.5.2" (from ccxt)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/72/991ee33a517df69c6cd6f3486cfe9b6329557cb55acaa8cefac33c
2aa4d2/aiodns-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=60.9.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from ccxt) (60.9.1)
Requirement already satisfied: multidict<7.0,>=4.5 in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from aiohttp>=3.8; pyth
on_version >= "3.5.2"->ccxt) (6.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: aiosignal>=1.1.2 in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from aiohttp>=3.8; python_
version >= "3.5.2"->ccxt) (1.2.0)
  Requirement already satisfied: asynctest==0.13.0; python_version < "3.8" in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (f
rom aiohttp>=3.8; python_version >= "3.5.2"->ccxt) (0.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<3.0,>=2.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from aiohttp>=
3.8; python_version >= "3.5.2"->ccxt) (2.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: async-timeout<5.0,>=4.0.0a3 in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from aiohttp>=3
.8; python_version >= "3.5.2"->ccxt) (4.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.7.4; python_version < "3.8" in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-pack
ages (from aiohttp>=3.8; python_version >= "3.5.2"->ccxt) (4.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.3.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from aiohttp>=3.8; python_ver
sion >= "3.5.2"->ccxt) (21.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: frozenlist>=1.1.1 in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from aiohttp>=3.8; python
_version >= "3.5.2"->ccxt) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.18.4
->ccxt) (1.26.8)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5; python_version >= "3" in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from re
quests>=2.18.4->ccxt) (3.3)
Collecting pycares>=4.0.0 (from aiodns>=1.1.1; python_version >= "3.5.2"->ccxt)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4c/5a/a82398e38049e689350f07b46dd8493a8a74821e39c2b904350a31
60c1cb/pycares-4.1.2-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.w
hl
Collecting cffi>=1.5.0 (from pycares>=4.0.0->aiodns>=1.1.1; python_version >= "3.5.2"->ccxt)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/00/9e/92de7e1217ccc3d5f352ba21e52398372525765b2e0c4530e6eb2b
a9282a/cffi-1.15.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from cffi>=1.5.0->pycares>=4.0.0-
>aiodns>=1.1.1; python_version >= "3.5.2"->ccxt) (2.21)
Building wheels for collected packages: cffi
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cffi ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-afnot
79o/cffi/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(c
ompile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-p40y4ye4 --python-tag cp37:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  running build_ext
  building '_cffi_backend' extension
  c/_cffi_backend.c:15:10: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory
   #include <ffi.h>
            ^~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
  
  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for cffi
  Running setup.py clean for cffi
Failed to build cffi
Installing collected packages: cffi, pycares, aiodns, ccxt
  Running setup.py install for cffi ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-afn
ot79o/cffi/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec
(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-yai9v9gy/install-record.txt --single-version-ex
ternally-managed --compile --user --prefix=:
    running install
    /home/dlqudgjs12/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:37: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarn
ing: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
      setuptools.SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning,
    running build
    running build_py
    running build_ext
    building '_cffi_backend' extension
    c/_cffi_backend.c:15:10: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory
     #include <ffi.h>
              ^~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-afnot79o/cffi/setup.py';f=g
etattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__,
 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-yai9v9gy/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compi
le --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-afnot79o/cffi/
```

i tried to solve this problem.

but i couldn't find right solution

also other packages..

pip3 install TA-lib

pip3 install pandas_ta

both packages are stoped during install..

Comment: Try **apt install libffi-dev** first.

Comment: @Byungheon Lee, If the answer was useful, please mark the answer as accepted for greater visibility for community and upvote if the answer has some useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Several reasons may trigger this error. To mention a few:

- Your system development libraries are missing.
- You may not be running pip from your virtual environment.
- You didn’t specify when you were installing PIL.

The `error : x86_64-Linux-gnu-gcc failed with exit status 1` can be triggered by missing system development libraries packages, installing these library packages can fix the problem.(e.g. ffi→ libffi, ssl → libssl).

Install the [appropriate packages](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/setup#linux) by the following command

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

or for a specific version of Python 3, replace x with the minor version in

```
sudo apt-get install python3.x-dev
```

Try this command for installing the library package.

```
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
```

Refer to the [link](https://linuxnetmag.com/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-failed/) for more information on why this error will trigger.